# Raid 10 implemented on server. Need to know about its performance when one of the disk fails

Tags: raid, raid10

Server will be implemented with raid 10 using two 4TB disks.Can anyone help me answering what will happen to the server if one of the disks fails will there be any interruptions on the server? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There will be no interruptions on the server and performance should be impacted negligibly. That is the advantage of using a stripe of mirrors  versus parity.
Recovery and any associated downtime will depend on the technology that you are using to implement RAID

Comment: +1. When a single disk fails, you still have your RAID0 array, but one of your RAID1 arrays is degraded, so your performance is unchanged until rebuild time.

Answer (score 0):

On RAID 10 one disk failure there is only impact during rebuilding array.
In case of HW RAID you set inside controller or in case of [SW LINUX RAID you can un/limit speed](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-raid-increase-resync-rebuild-speed.html)